# Observable.Using disposes on other thread than created on

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, system.reactive

I have an ASP.NET WebApi request method which in turn starts an asynchronous call using `Observable.Using` on a legacy resource. This resource will spawn a new thread on which it raises events which in turn are converted to `OnNext` items in an `IObservable` stream exposed by a wrapper around the resource.

I am `await`ing the result of the stream using `IObservable.FirstOrDefaultAsync()` and my WebApi method is marked `async`.

If I go with this setup, I will get the infamous

> An asynchronous module or handler 
>   completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending

So, my first question is regarding this. I assume I'm getting this since new asynchronous operations (no `async`/`await`) are spawned by the legacy resource, but how exactly does ASP.NET know this? What has been registered? I have found out that ASP.NET is looking at the `SynchronizationContext.Current._state.VoidAsyncOutstandingOperationCount` in order to raise this exception, but which calls increments this property? Threads queued to the ThreadPool? I am fairly certain this is being made by the legacy resource.

Now why are these operations still going when I'm disposing my resource? Well, it appears `Dispose` is run on the thread on which events are propagated, similar in concept to the below snippet.

```
Observable
    .Using(
        () => {
            Console.WriteLine($"Created on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            return Disposable.Create(() => {
                Console.WriteLine($"Disposed on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}");
            });
        },
        _ => Observable.Return(1, NewThreadScheduler.Default))
    .Do(_ => Console.WriteLine($"OnNext on thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId}"))
    .Wait();
```

Result similar to this:

```
Created on thread: 10
OnNext on thread: 11
Disposed on thread: 11
```

Is this by design? When disposing a resource using `using`, it's obvious that the resource is disposed on the same thread that created it since the code is synchronous. With the `Dispose` being run on a separate thread, the calling code will continue running and the controller will return before the `Dispose` is fully completed (most of the time, at least).

How can I mitigate this in a sane way? One way that seem to work is to, instead of using `Observable.Using`, using this construct which is returned to the controller, `await`ing it using `FirstOrDefaultAsync()`:

```
var resource = // Creating resource manually.
return resource.StartAsyncOperation() // <- observable producing events
    .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
    .Do(_ => resource.Dispose());
```

This feels like a hack to me though.

Thoughts and recommendations?

### Edit 1

I guess one of the problems I'm facing here is that the `Dispose` method of the resource is called *after* the sequence is terminated/completed when I'm using `Observable.Using`. Should this be the case? There's really no way of waiting for the `Dispose` using that construct in that case. I'd have to amend the api with an additional `IObservable<Unit> Disposed()` method or something like that...

Comment: Regarding your first question, please post the stack trace.

Comment: @shay__: there's no stack trace. "An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending" is the only thing showing and if you look at the IL code it's really not throwing any exception (just creating the `InvalidOperationException` and then passing it along to some exception handler thing.

Answer (score 1):

The `Dispose` will be called on the thread that calls it (well duh). To be more helpful, when a Rx sequence is consumed/observed on another thread that is where the `OnComplete` callback will be called. If you are using Rx with the standard operators, then you will get auto disposal behavior when the sequence terminates (with either `OnError` or `OnComplete`). This auto disposal will just happen straight after the `OnComplete`/`OnError` and will just run on the same thread.

If you want your disposal to be bound to a scheduler then I would suggest looking at the `System.Reactive.Disposables.ScheduledDisposable` type. However it appears that using a `SynchronizationContext` is more natural here, so in that case `System.Reactive.Disposables.ContextDisposable` is probably more suitable.

Comment: `System.Reactive.Disposables.ContextDisposable` is interesting! I'm going to try that. However, I still wonder about the design that makes it difficult to ensure that `Dispose` has been run after `OnCompleted` is called when using `Observable.Using`. Or perhaps something in my understanding of this is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: If you are worried about the use case when the sequence has been completed and then auto disposes; then I would assume that the `Dispose` is called once the `OnComplete` has finished running. However this does not mean that the `Dispose` will always follow the `OnComplete`. In the case where the subscription is terminated before the sequence is completed, you will see the disposal fire without an `OnComplete`.